# Disabled RadNumericTextbox not maintaining value after postback

Tags: .net, vb.net, telerik

I have this javascript code:

```
var RadNumericTextBox1 = $find("RadNumericTextBox1");
RadNumericTextBox1.set_value(10);
RadNumericTextBox1.disable();
```

After postback in VB, Me.RadNumericTextBox1.Value = 0. How can I submit the new value?

Answer (score 0):

you can use session variables to store value instead of this

```
var RadNumericTextBox1 = $find("RadNumericTextBox1");
session("RadNumericTextBox1")=10;
RadNumericTextBox1.set_value(session("RadNumericTextBox1"));
```

you can access the value to any where till the session get abondend